# HTTP request received with status 200 and without body

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am making small CRUD app with authentication in React, Node and MySQL.
Beginner in all of this. So, I fetch the data from back-end, received on client side with status 200, but body is empty. In Chrome developer tools, network tab, I see data received in response. Front-end, back-end and DB are all on one machine
Code:

```
return fetch(`http://localhost:4000/authenticate?email=${email}&password=${password}`)        
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            response.json()
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            // login successful if there's a id in the response
            if (response.id) {
                // store user details in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response));
                dispatch(success(response));
                dispatch(alertActions.clear());
                history.push('/');
            } else {
                dispatch(failure(response.message));
                dispatch(alertActions.error(response.message));
                //dispatch(logout());
            }
```

Server:

```
app.get('/authenticate', (req, res) => {
    let answer = { message: ''}
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '${req.query.email}'`;
    console.log(sql)
    let query = db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        console.log(result)
        if(err) {
            throw err
        } else {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                if (result[0].password === req.query.password) {
                    res.send(result)
                } else {
                    answer.message = 'Email and Password does not match!'
                    console.log(answer)
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(answer))
                    res.send(JSON.stringify(answer))
                }
            } else {
                answer.message = 'Email does not exists!'
                res.send(JSON.stringify(answer))
            }
        }      
    })
});
```

Comment: You're saying in the Chrome network tab you see data, but in your code it's empty?  What does the `console.log(response)` display?

Comment: why are you making 2 then. In the second one the response will be undefined

Comment: if the body is empty, it's probably a server issue. What does the server code that handles this request look like?

Comment: Response
body:(...)
bodyUsed:true
headers:Headers {}
ok:true
redirected:false
status:200
statusText:"OK"
type:"cors"
url:"http://localhost:4000/authenticate?email=mio@gmail.com&password=123"
__proto__:Response -- This is display. @Tarek Essam: issue is that first response does not contain body. Server returns what is expected, I updated post with code from server.

Comment: @Henry Woody: Server returns what is expected, I updated post with code from server

Comment: Based on what you've put there, @Scott's answer is correct, basically you are calling `.json()` on the response and then discarding the result. When interpreting the output of `console.log`, particularly when it comes to objects, bear in mind that there may be a lag between when it is called and when it is written; in this case, anything on the response that indicates that its body has been consumed will be from _after_ the call to `.json()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `response.json()` so that your next `then` can receive it.  Change this:

```
.then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    response.json()
})
```

To:

```
.then(response => {
    return response.json()
})
```

Or even shorter as:

```
.then(response => response.json())
```

UPDATE: After seeing your server code, there's another thing you can try.  You need to ensure you are responding with JSON. Here, try changing this line:

```
 res.send(result)
```

To:

```
 return res.json(result);
```

Comment: Issue is that first response does not contain body

Comment: But it does.  What happens when you try this? `.then(response => response.json()).then(responseBody => {console.log(responseBody)})`